Unable to overwrite image using matplotlib (plt.savefig())
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
make any plot
plt.savefig('plots/fly_RC.pdf', bbox_inches = 'tight')
If fly_RC.pdf already exists then it gives permission error and doesn't overwrite the file:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'plots/fly_RC.pdf'

However, if fly_RC.pdf doesn't exist then it creates it without an issue.
I keep coming across this error whenever I have to modify an old plot of mine.
What's wrong? Never had this problem before.

This usually happens when the .pdf is open in another software, like adobe or similar, are you sure that this isn't the case?
I was able to replicate the same error by keeping the .pdf open in an editor:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make a plot on fake data
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25])
plt.savefig('data/output/plot.pdf')
plt.show()

Error:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'data/output/plot.pdf'


Bonus:
The same does not happen if you open the pdf on a browser

Nope, that's definitely not the case for me.

The same does happen even if you convert the .ipynb into a .py?
